# How to resize image with percent in powertoys

Tags: windows-10, images, powertoys

I am using the image resizer tool in powertoys to resize multiple images at once. The problem is when I switch the unit to percent, there is still the option width like image below.

[image]

I also tried to set the width to 50 (I thought it's like 50% with ratio locked) but it seems does not work.

I am using Windows 10 64 bits.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Use Irfanview instead. https://www.techovity.com/batch-resize-images-using-irfanview/

Comment: @Gantendo I have tried your solution and it works really well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Irfanview is awesome. yvw